# Changing the mode of the cursor in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am working on a WebGL application and I want to use the cursor to turn the camera. The problem is, with the regular cursor, as soon as it leaves the window there is no more movement detected. Is there a way to change the behavior of the cursor, so that it can't leave the window and I only get the change of the cursor position?

Comment: For hopefully obvious reasons, you can't just arbitrarily do this. But you can "request pointer lock" under certain circumstances. Have a look into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As "Niet the Dark Absol" said, you need to request a pointer lock. Mozilla has a nice page on how to do that: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Pointer_Lock_API